# APK Re-sign JAR

Tags: android, certificate, apk

I want to install the Amazone2.2.apk on my emulator and want to run it from my automaton script for testing. For this we have to resign it. Could you please let me know how i can do this? I have done same thing with evernote successfully but it is not working for amazone. while installation of amazone2.2.debug.apk i am getting eror:

73 KB/s (3882442 bytes in 51.512s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/Amazon_2.2.2_debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]

Query: Install Amazon.apk to debug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sign an APK with a debug certificate, use [testsign.jar](https://code.google.com/p/zen-droid/downloads/detail?name=testsign.jar&can=2&q=). The usage is very simple and doesn't require you to even create a test key.

> Usage: testsign input.jar [output.jar]

You would use something like this:

> java -jar testsign.jar Amazon_2.2.2_debug.apk Amazon_2.2.2_debug-signed.apk
>
> adb install Amazon_2.2.2_debug-signed.apk

Comment: Thanks, Could you let me know how to find out the class name and the activity name. As per me it should be "com.amazon.mShop.android" and "com.amazon.mShop.androidcom.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity". but it is not working getting ClassNotFoundException

Comment: You shouldn't need to know the package name or any of the activity names to resign. All of this info is available in the manifest.

FYI "com.amazon.mShop.android" seems like it's a package name, which I think is what you meant. This: "com.amazon.mShop.androidcom.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity" looks like the package name was duplicated.

What are you doing to get this error?

Comment: Actually i need to run this amazon app from my script on emulator.. for this i need the activity name and the class name....

Comment: Try this:
    am start -n com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity

Comment: I am trying to fire the jar but it gives me this error `no main manifest attribute, in testsign.jar` . What am I doing wrong ?